# HTTPS authentication with local unix user

Tags: user-accounts, https, authentication

I have an Ubuntu desktop machine running Apache, connected to the workplace LAN. All users of my team have unix accounts on this machine. Is it possible to allow some webpages to be served via https only with password protection, and with username and password authenticated by the unix system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using third-party modules such as [mod_authnz_pam](https://www.adelton.com/apache/mod_authnz_pam/), or [mod_authn_sasl](http://mod-authn-sasl.sourceforge.net/) (when configured to use saslauthd as the pwcheck method – which itself then calls PAM).